# Retrofit/Moshi request gives error - java.lang.IllegalStateException : dangling name

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

I'm using Retrofit to make some API calls.

Recently, I added a new endpoint

```
@POST("api/test/myRequest")
    fun createRequest(
        @retrofit2.http.Body request: MyRequest
    ): Single<MyResponse>
```

Using the following DataClass to represent the non-serialized request

```
data class MyRequest(
    @Json(name = "myData") @field:Json(name = "myData") var myData: String,
    @Json(name = "myuuid") @field:Json(name = "myuuid") var myuuid: UUID? = null
)
```

When I try to make the request, it fails with the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dangling name: myuuid

The top item in the stacktrace is: com.squareup.moshi.JsonUtf8Writer.  It seems Moshi is throwing an error when trying to serialize the request.  It's not clear to me why though.

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use only one of the annotations, for instance you get the issue if you do not use `@Json(` name, but only `@field`
I am not sure and could cancel this post if did not help you, but please try, I am quite curious